# Link library with cmake

Tags: cmake

I installed the library `bcm2835` on my pc. To compile a program in c I must type:

```
gcc -o my_program my_program.c -l rt -l bcm2835
```

Now I must compile another program that use the same libraries with `cmake`. I have never used this.
What must I add to the bottom of "cmakelists.txt"?

I have tried:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_program rt)  
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_program bcm2835)
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Any error messages or explanation of what doesn't work?

Answer (score 8):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project( my_program )

find_library( rt_lib rt OTHER_PARAMETERS_THAT_YOU_REQUIRE_SEE_DOCUMENTATION_LINK )
find_library( bcm2835_lib bcm2835 OTHER_PARAMETERS_THAT_YOU_REQUIRE_SEE_DOCUMENTATION_LINK )

include_directories( LIST_OF_REQUIRED_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_SEE_DOCUMENTATION_LINK ) 

add_executable( my_program my_program.c )
target_link_libraries( my_program rt_lib bcm2835_lib )
```

Here are some examples:

- [CMake examples on cmake.org](https://cmake.org/examples/)
- [CMake tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html)
- [How To Find Libraries](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries)

Since CMake has good documentation, you should read more about the commands [in the latest CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/)

Also, `cmakelists.txt` files should be named `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: This really should be marked as an answer it clearly works and solved the asker's problem, and the asker clearly won't mark it complete.